# Matching several lines with either keywords or plain text

Tags: python, pyparsing

```py
import pyparsing as pp

pp.ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(" \t")

# End of line. Clean it off.
NL = pp.LineEnd().suppress()

repeat_stmt = pp.Keyword("REPEAT") + pp.pyparsing_common.number()

end_stmt = pp.Keyword("END")

statement = (repeat_stmt | end_stmt)
text = pp.Group(~statement + pp.restOfLine)

structure = pp.ZeroOrMore(statement | text)
structure.ignore(NL)

DATA = """
line 1
line 2
a bit longer line 3
REPEAT 123
foo bar
END
"""

print(structure.parseString(DATA))
```

I'm trying to build rather simple text generator with pyparsing.

Given above code I would expect get non keyword lines copied as is and parse keywords (currently all two of them).

Above code only end up in infinite loop

I would expect output to be something along the lines:

```py
[
 ['line 2'], ['line 2'], ['a bit longer line 3'],
 [['REPEAT', 123]], ['foo bar'] [['END'],
]
```

How I can achieve that?

Comment: Apparently I had totally incorrect example code. Sorry for that. Fixed it.

Comment: If you write a context-free grammar, it's also a generative grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable debugging on NL parsing, using setDebug,

```
NL = pp.LineEnd().suppress().setDebug()
```

you'll see that NL loops forever at the end of the input string.  You can break this loop while the ZeroOrMore using stopOn:

```
structure = pp.ZeroOrMore(statement | text, stopOn=pp.StringEnd())
```

With this change, you'll get:

```
[['line 1'], ['line 2'], ['a bit longer line 3'], 'REPEAT', 123, ['foo bar'], 'END', ['']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much (again). That debug tip was really valuable.